# Axioms for a symmetric monoidal bicategory

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

I start reading the axioms for a symmetric monoidal bicategory. The axioms include so many diagrams to be satisfied. I am wondering if people really use these axioms directly to check a given data is a symmetric monoidal bicategory. Or is there any criteria that makes it easier to do this job.

Comment: Mike Shulman has a paper you may like: http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.0993.

Comment: Update, and to add more context: one of the applications of Shulman's construction is [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08100) of K. Courser.